# SQL query with sub query with IN or LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 50 rows in which are replication articles.  I need to pick up these names and query sys.sql_modules to see if the article name exists anywhere inside the definition (proc text).  I've tried the below based on a similar suggestion from another thread on here but it reports all rows back which I'm not expecting;

```
SELECT Article,
       CASE WHEN exists (SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS name,
                                definition
                         FROM sys.sql_modules
                         WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsProcedure') = 1
                           AND definition LIKE '%database%') 
              THEN 'YES else'
           ELSE article
       END
FROM dbo.Article
```

Maybe I need to try querying it the other way around?  So populate a temp table with the syntax from all stored procedures and then query the article name against that?

Comment: You have no where clause there, of course all rows will be returned, unless you're saying the case statement is returning the wrong value. Please provide a screenshot of the query output.

Comment: ^^ Not a screenshot please - copy and paste _text_ of the query output. combine with text tables of the input tables, and text of what you would expect the output to be.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Or that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no relationship between the article and the module.  I am guessing that you want to find `Article` in the `definition`, which suggests logic like this:

```
SELECT a.Article, m.definition
FROM dbo.Article a JOIN
     sys.sql_modules m
     ON OBJECTPROPERTY(m.object_id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 AND
        m.definition LIKE '%database%' AND
        m.definition LIKE '%' + a.Article_Name + '%'
```

I don't know if the condition on "database" is needed, but it is part of your original question.

Comment: That's the ticket thanks Gordon!  I didn't need database name but put that in for hiding of names etc.  I've run the code provided and it's worked fine, from a glance it looks like the data returned matches what I was intending on producing.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery isnt' linked to the query, I assume that is what you mean by "exist anywhere".

In the code bellow, it search only the article name in object definition. CHARINDEX is used instead of LIKE to search if article exists within the definition.

```
SELECT Article,
       CASE WHEN exists (SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS name,
                                definition
                         FROM sys.sql_modules
                         WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsProcedure') = 1
                           AND  CHARINDEX(article, definition) > 0) 
              THEN 'YES else'
           ELSE article
       END
FROM dbo.Article
```